# Can I get executed commands not using history or ~/.bash_history?

Tags: c, linux, exec

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("entering main process---\n");
    int ret;
    char *argv[] = {"history",NULL};
    ret = execvp("history",argv);
    if(ret == -1) 
        perror("execl error");
    printf("exiting main process ----\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
entering main process---
execl error: No such file or directory
exiting main process ----

Question:
  Can I get executed commands not using history or ~/.bash_history?

It seems that something is wrong using function like execvp .
I've tried system function.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    system("history");
    return 0 ; 
}
```

Nothing output.

Comment: The history command is a shell built-in, not a separate command.

Comment: Thanks. Can I get executed commands  not using history or ~/.bash_history?

Comment: @ttworkhard If that's what you're trying to do now, make sure you update the question.

Comment: Does `system("history");` not work?

Comment: Yes , I've tried to use system("history"). There is no output. It works when i use system("ls /home") instead of history.

Comment: Just saying ... `system()` also does an `exec()` ...

Comment: `system` spawns a new shell (possibly not 100% true - I think it just does a fork/exec if there are no shell metacharacters in the command). So it has no history to output. I very much doubt that bash provides an API for programs run from the shell can access their parent shell's history.

Answer (score 1):

If you try a `man history` you will get into the `BASH_BUILTINS(1) General Commands Manual` page. This means history is part of the `bash` shell internals. In order to have something executed via `execvp()` you need to have an actual executable somewhere in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why reading `~/.bash_history` is not enough. Is it perhaps because you want the history of the currently running shell?

The short answer is no, you can't get it.

The long answer is you could attach with `ptrace` or through `/proc/pid/mem`, find the history in memory, and print it.
Probably not worth the effort.

You can pipe the output of the history builtin if you wish, by running your program with

```
history | ./myprog
```